# Equinox p2 without all the eclipse bundles?

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, equinox

Is it possible to use equinox p2 in and simple java application without all the eclipse stuff?

Cause i started with the osgi, equinox and equinox p2 bundles and have been adding osgi bundles for over an hour now. And every time i try to run the program another dependency comes up as missing.

I now already have 109 bundles including a lot of eclipse bundles. Is there maybe an easier way of finding out the minimum required bundles of equinox p2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The smallest consistent set of equinox OSGi and p2 is provided via OSGi starter kits. Give them a try. From the [Equinox Stable Build: Mars](http://download.eclipse.org/equinox/drops/R-Mars-201506032000/index.php) click on the triangular **OSGi starter kits** and download the appropriate version for you platform.

Comment: Excellent, i downloaded it, added it as target, created a runnable and it works immediately. Going from 159 plugins to 52!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [bndtools](https://github.com/bndtools/bndtools). In Bndtools, we area building a p2 repository in our [CI build](https://bndtools.ci.cloudbees.com/job/bndtools.master/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/build/generated/p2/) for Bndtools itself (Bndtools is an Eclipse plugin build with Bndtools without using PDE). Neil Bartlett has spent significant time to get this to work and I don't think he requires 109 bundles ...

Comment: Cheers!, i bumped into bndtools last evening while surfing on my couch, even watched the video on youtube. I had planned on installing it today, because it seems to ease development of osgi bundles, especially handy for end users that aren't over familiar with osgi meta info.

Comment: go for it! it will help you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Press the Add Required Bundles button the the plugins or bundles tab in your launch configuration. Then press the Validate button to make sure you have no remaining errors due to unresolvable dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with p2 - figuring out the minimal set of p2 bundles. This is what I came up with (partial MANIFEST.MF):

```
 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository;bundle-version="1.1.300",
 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core;bundle-version="2.3.0",
 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director;bundle-version="2.3.100",
 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.discovery;bundle-version="1.0.300",
 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine;bundle-version="2.3.0",
 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata;bundle-version="2.2.0",
 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository;bundle-version="1.2.100",
 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.operations;bundle-version="2.4.0",
 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository;bundle-version="2.3.0",
 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.eclipse;bundle-version="2.1.200",
 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.touchpoint.natives;bundle-version="1.1.100",
 org.eclipse.equinox.frameworkadmin,
 org.eclipse.equinox.frameworkadmin.equinox;bundle-version="1.0.500",
 org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator
```

This code is about 7 months old, so some bundle versions may be different now.